# React hooks - wait until the state has been updated

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I'm using the useState() hook, and I've found that my app has a bug, because setting the value is asynchronous. So if I have code like this:

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const res = await fetchData()
      console.log(data); // []
      setData(res.data.hits);
      console.log(res.data.hits); // Array full of objects
      console.log(data); // Still []
    }
    getData()
  }, [fetchData]);
```

How can I execute some specific logic only when the new state has actually been set?

Comment: Even if it weren't asynchronous, `data` is still declared with `const` - it won't change

Comment: What sort of "execute something" do you want? A side-effect, like an API call? Or do you want to change what's rendered, or something else?

Comment: Add a new effect that watches `data`

Comment: why don't you use conditional rendering? once the data are available then it will execute.

Comment: @CertainPerformance The setState method has a callback when the state is updated. I'm looking for something similar to that.

Comment: @SwordI Not looking for rendering logic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `useEffect` [hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

```
useEffect(() => {
   //your code
}, [data]);
```

That will trigger what is inside every time `data` changes.

Comment: In general - yes, this is the correct answer. But my specific problem is that I have another useEffect() which depends on other different properties, and when it gets triggered, it still has the old state of the data variable.

Comment: Maybe you can simply trigger a function right after your `const res = await fetchData();` with `res` as a parameter that will execute the logic you want?

Comment: Not really, because the logic I want to execute is another useEffect() call which has other variables as dependencies.

Comment: And add the  `data` as a dependency of your other useEffect?

Comment: I don't want the other useEffect to run every time 'data' changes.

Comment: What about switching your data from `const [data, setData] = useState([]);` to `let data = [];`. Do you need a new render each time data changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform some logic to ensure the "specific logic" you want is executed after your setData is done from that specific call and not from other setData calls,

For example,

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([])
 const [runSpecific, setRunSpecific] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const res = await fetchData()
      console.log(data); // []
      setData(res.data.hits);
      setRunSpecific(true);
      console.log(res.data.hits); // Array full of objects
      console.log(data); // Still []
    }
    getData()
  }, [fetchData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(runSpecific){
       "specific Logic" you want to run
    }
    setRunSpecific(false)
  }, [data]);
```

In essence, every time the data changes, it executes your "specific logic" only when `runSpecific` is true, which can only be true from that initial call.

So you need not worry when about other SetData calls.

Answer (score 0):

With react 18, useEffect runs twice, but even with that, your logic will work here!

```js
 const [data, setData] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const res = await fetchData()
      setData(res.data.hits);
    }
    if(!data.length){
      // logic for the time, when the state has not been updated yet
      getData()
    }else if(data.length){
      // logic for the time, when the state has been updated
      console.log("state is", state)
    }
  }, [data]); // only use [data], no need to put fetchData in the array
```